# Query that evaluated ParentChild table summing up elements over whole structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

to display a products structure that is build from assemblies (A) that may contains other assemblies and parts (P) our database has a simple table "ParentChild" that shows the relaation of a parent (assembly) and its children with the quantity, how often the child is contained.

as tree this would look like:

```
A1
 |-(1x) A2
 |       |-(2x)- P1
 |       |-(1x)- P2
 |
 |-(2x) A3
         |-(1x)- A4
                 |-(3x)- P1
                 |-(1x)- P3
```

This is stored in a simple table like this:

```
Parent  Child   Quantity
A1      A2      2
A1      A3      1
A2      P1      2
A2      P2      1
A3      A4      1
A4      P1      3
A4      P3      1
```

I need to sum up the parts only with the overall quantity. Expected result:

```
Sum of all P in A1:
8x P1
1x P2 
2x P3
```

Does anyone has a query that achieves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is not too big, this following solution should do:

```sql
;WITH
  cte AS
    (
      SELECT Parent, Child, 1 AS t_Quantity, Quantity, 1 AS depth FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Child LIKE 'P_'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        t.Parent, cte.Child,  t.Quantity, cte.Quantity * t.Quantity AS Quantity, cte.depth + 1 AS depth
      FROM cte
        INNER JOIN dbo.TestTable t ON t.Child = cte.Parent
    )
SELECT
  a.Child, SUM(a.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT
    *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Child ORDER BY cte.depth DESC) AS rk
  FROM cte
) a
WHERE parent = 'A1'
GROUP BY a.Child
ORDER BY a.Child;
```

The cte expression has two parts. The first SELECT collects all leafs and marks them with depth=1. The second SELECT finds the parent for the leaf and inserts its parent in the first column, increasing the depth by one. Recursion of the CTE continues until no additional parent can be found.

After collecting all the data, we only need to sum up all nodes having the root as parent, all others are just intermedidate results.

When using ctes, you have to make sure they recurse not too deep, because that will be really costly and may fail because of memory limits (global limit is 100 recursions)

PS: your sample data has the Amounts of the frst two rows switched

Comment: your query works perfectly. I had an error in my sample data bringing me into endless loop :-)

Comment: are you really located in Hessen, Germany? We might be neighbours!

Comment: could be - I work in Frankfurt, live near Mannheim...

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun one for me. First the solution I came up with:

```sql
declare @desiredParent char(2) = 'A1';

with yourData as (
    select * from (values
        ('A1', 'A2', 1),
        ('A1', 'A3', 2),
        ('A2', 'P1', 2),
        ('A2', 'P2', 1),
        ('A3', 'A4', 1),
        ('A4', 'P1', 3),
        ('A4', 'P3', 1)
    ) as x(Parent, Child, Quantity)
), cte as (
    select *, 
        TotalQuantity = Quantity,
        h = cast( concat('/', Parent, '/') as varchar(max) ),
        ph = cast( '/' as varchar(max) )
    from yourData
    where Parent = @desiredParent

    union all

    select child.*, 
        TotalQuantity = parent.TotalQuantity * child.Quantity,
        h = cast( concat(parent.h, child.Child, '/') as varchar(max) ),
        ph = parent.h
    from cte as parent
    join yourData as child
        on parent.child = child.Parent
)
select Child, sum(TotalQuantity)
from cte
where not exists (
    select 1
    from cte as b
    where b.ph = cte.h
)
group by Child;
```

Note - there was some discrepancy between your ASCII art of the hierarchy, the data you say is in the table, and the results you're looking for; the art and the results matched so I massaged the data to match.

By way of exposition, the yourData cte is just a convenient way for me to inline the data - it could just as easily come from your actual table. The second cte is more or less a standard recursive cte but with some additional elements.

- TotalQuantity represents the quantity of that part in that branch of the hierarchy.
- h is a character representation of the hierarchy
- ph is a character representation of the hierarchy of this element's parent

The last query finds elements that are not parents of any other element (i.e. they are the leaf nodes in the tree) and then sums them up.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what is the partition...clause in Geepy's answer for?

This seems to bring same results?

I also replaced the "like P%" by a subquery to identify those elements that does not have children, but that should be same for these sample data

```
 WITH
   cte AS
     (
       SELECT Parent, Child, 1 AS t_Quantity, Qty, 1  AS depth FROM dbo.PC 
            WHERE Child not in (select Parent from PC)   
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
         t.Parent, cte.Child,  t.Qty, cte.Qty * t.Qty AS Quantity, cte.depth + 1 AS depth
       FROM cte
         INNER JOIN dbo.PC t ON t.Child = cte.Parent
     )
 SELECT
   Child, SUM(Qty) AS Quantity
   FROM cte 
 WHERE Parent = 'A1'
 GROUP BY Child
 ORDER BY Child
```

Comment: You're right, the PARTITION BY ist a remainder of a previous attempt to solve the problem presented, it is not needed for the solution